# Jenkins job status on GitHub

Tags: build, jenkins-plugins

Scenario: When a PR is created in GitHub, it will trigger a Jenkins Multibranch pipeline to execute CI for the fork and will post the Jenkins job status on GitHub PR page for that fork.

Jenkins job is getting triggered automatically with the help of GitHub personal access tokens and Webhook. But Jenkins job status is not shown/posted anywhere on GitHub. Getting below error:

**"Could not update commit status, please check if your scan credentials belong to a member of the organization or a collaborator of the repository and repo:status scope is selected
GitHub has been notified of this commit’s build result"**

Tried to post status using "GitHub autostatus" plugin, as per console output, getting below:

[Console output snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFTue.png)

Tried ignoring GitHub Hooks problems and others. Note: I am admin of the repo, still facing this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm the author of the Github Autostatus plugin.

I think the problem is that whichever user ID Jenkins is using to run the job needs to be added to your github repo as a collaborator. If you open "Configure" from the project in Jenkins representing your github org, you should have a user configured that has access to github, e.g.

[image]

That user needs access to your repo - the easiest way to do that is add them as a collaborator in github

Comment: Thanks, it was resolved earlier. I missed to update the question.